# Is there a Filesize Limit for Reading GDBs using Fiona?

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, fiona, limitations

I have python code that currently works fine with a GDB whose size is about ~ 82.7MB.  However when I try to use the same code against a GDB whose size ~ 612.8MB the code seems to hang eventually leading to the script terminating.

Specifically the code where the hang takes place is (first line):

```
buildingFeatures = [pt for pt in fiona.open(sourceDatabaseFile, 'r', layer=layer1)]

waterFeatures = [pol for pol in fiona.open(sourceDatabaseFile, 'r', layer=layer2)]

    for building in buildingFeatures:
        buildingShape = shape(building['geometry'])

        #if the geometry intersects the spatial index
        for id in idx.intersection(buildingShape.bounds):
            water = waterFeatures[id]

            #Check to see if current hydrographySrf feature intersection is a perennial water
            if (('ZI024_HYP' in water['properties']) and (water['properties']['ZI024_HYP'] == 1)):
                waterShapeGeometry = shape(water['geometry'])

                #Check to see if perennial water actually contains building point
                if waterShapeGeometry.contains(buildingShape):
                    discoveredBuildingsContainedInWaters.append(building['id'])
```

Is there a better way to open a large GDB using Fiona or is there some sort of size limit for GDBs used with Fiona?

Comment: It's not so much "opening" a file geodatabase so much as reading the entire contents into memory that's causing your difficulty.  That makes this more of a pure Python coding issue than a GIS one.

Comment: @Vince         Is there a better algorithm you'd recommend to read a layer chunks at a time to approach this problem?

Comment: It's hard to believe the documentation wouldn't address this.

Answer (score 1):

So I rewrote some of my code to exclude properties I was not interested in storing to minimize my memory footprint.  In addition I closed file streams just in case.

```
for bldg in buildingLayerList:
    with fiona.open(sourceDatabaseFile, 'r', layer=bldg) as sourceFile1:
        for building in sourceFile1:
            buildingFeatures.append((building['id'], building['geometry']))
        sourceFile1.close()

    #Use current list of buildings and compare against all hydrography layers
    for hydro in hydrographyLayerList:
        with fiona.open(sourceDatabaseFile, 'r', layer=hydro) as sourceFile2:
            for water in sourceFile2:
                waterFeatures.append((water['id'], water['geometry'], water['properties']))
            sourceFile2.close()

        #from rtree import index
        idx = index.Index() #Create an R-Tree index and store the features in it (bounding box)
        for pos, poly in enumerate(waterFeatures):
            idx.insert(pos, shape(poly[1]).bounds)

        for building in buildingFeatures:
            buildingShape = shape(building[1])

            #if the geometry intersects the spatial index
            for id in idx.intersection(buildingShape.bounds):
                water = waterFeatures[id]

                #Check to see if current hydrography feature intersection is a perennial water
                if (('ZI024_HYP' in water[2]) and (water[2]['ZI024_HYP'] == 1)):
                    waterShapeGeometry = shape(water[1])
                    numBoundedBldgHydroFeaturesEvaluated += 1

                    #Check to see if perennial water actually contains building feature
                    if waterShapeGeometry.contains(buildingShape):
                        discoveredBuildingsContainedInWaters.append(building[0])

            if len(discoveredBuildingsContainedInWaters) > 0:
                totalBldgIDs.update({bldg + " vs " + hydro: sorted(discoveredBuildingsContainedInWaters)})

        discoveredBuildingsContainedInWaters[:] = [] # Just in case
        waterFeatures[:] = [] # Just in case
    buildingFeatures[:] = [] # Just in case
```

The end result was I got much further parsing through the GDB but the code eventually terminated for the same reasons Vince stated previously before.

I got a hold of the administrator of the server I was running my script on and found out that the environment I was running in had 16GB of RAM shared between all concurrently logged in users (typically at least 6 users).  It also turns out that the environment was not set up with a swap file therefore it was purely RAM.  The administrator added an 8GB swap file and this fixed my problems.

For the sake of characterizing my problem, the GDB I was using had the following feature count of building vs. hydrography layers:

StructurePnt - 1,533,842 features

StructureCrv - 476 features

HydrographySrf - 7,729 features

HydrographyCrv - 60,090 features

Worst-Case scenario was 92,168,565,780 permutations (StructurePnt vs HydrographyCrv)